# Capturar el tiempo de retorno RESPONSE en petición http con RETROFIT

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una duda. Estoy realizando una petición http con Retrofit y el valor me retorna con normalidad. Quisiera saber como puedo yo capturar el tiempo en el que me retorna **response.body()** desde el servidor porque a ese tiempo desearía sumarle 3000 milisegundos:

```js
codeVerificationEmail.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Validate>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Validate>?, response: Response<Validate>?) {
                val validate = response!!.body()
                if (validate != null) {
                    if(validate.esValido){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Codigo verificado en true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Codigo verificado en false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Validate>?, t: Throwable?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
```

Si alguien me guiaría o ayudaría le agradezco de antemano, estoy recién aprendiendo programación en Android y estoy un poco desorientado en este problema

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el callback `onResponse()` puedes obtener este valor a partir de `response`

```
    //Tiempo cuando se realizo la peticiòn
    long requestTime = response.raw().sentRequestAtMillis();

    //Tiempo que duro la respuesta
    long responseTime = response.raw().receivedResponseAtMillis();

    //Tiempo transcurrido por la peticiòn
    long timeElapsed =  responseTime - requestTime;
```